# Multiple Show Hide Function with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Currently I am developing a simple show/hide div function with JavaScript. Now I have made it partially work. Take a look or you can copy and paste and try my code on your com. Here is the code:

http://jsfiddle.net/HRn3Q/

The current problem is I don't know how to trigger the content in the drop down list and show/hide it at the same position as graph1, graph2 and graph3 etc...I also want something like when diagram 1 is being shown then when I click show div 2, the content of diagram 1 will be replaced by graph2. I hope I have state my question clear.

Comment: If you are new to JS, I recommend you this page: http://jsfiddle.net/ It allows you sharing JS/HTML code and let us check and study your problem easily ;-)

Comment: Just a tip, you're creating global variables all over the place: when, inside a function, you're writing something like `for (x=1;x<=3;x++)`, without a prior declaration of variable `x`, `x` gets set as a global variable. Best to start your functions with a line like `var x,y,z;` to prevent that from happening, bc it _will_ cause issues sooner or later.

Comment: [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qx4Lc/) based on the code you supplied, but it's not working.

Comment: thank you. But I can run my code with dreamweaver and eclipse. Could you run it with other tools?

Answer (score 0):

This should do it.
The page wasn't recognizing the functions in that state for some reason.

turned:

```
function toggleStock(id)
{
}
```

into:

```
toggleStock = function(id)
{
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HRn3Q/

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    var opacity =0;
    var intervalId =0;

    function fadein() 
    {
        intervalId = setInterval(hide,200)  
    }
    
    function hide()
    {
        var img = document.getElementById("img1");
        opacity = Number(window.getComputedStyle(img).getPropertyValue("opacity"));
        if(opacity>0)
        {
            opacity=opacity-0.2;
            img.style.opacity=opacity;
        }
        else
        {
            clearInterval(intervalId);
        }
    }

    function fadeout()
    {
        intervalId = setInterval(show,200)
    }
    function show()
    {
        var img = document.getElementById("img1");
        opacity = Number(window.getComputedStyle(img).getPropertyValue("opacity"));
        if(opacity<1)
        {
            opacity=opacity+0.1;
            img.style.opacity= opacity;
        }
        else
        {
            clearInterval(intervalId);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Please, add some comments about what your code does!